# How can I make a symbolic link inside a directory like `ln -s TARGET DIRECTORY` does?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make a soft link inside a directory with a Perl script.

I can use `ln` to create a link to `/home/apuntes` inside the directory `/home/scripts` like this:

```
ln -s /home/apuntes /home/scripts
```

But I don't know how to do this with Perl. I tried

```
symlink("home/apuntes", "home/scripts");
```

but it didn't create the link and there are no errors. Can anyone help me?

Comment: PD: I can not use system calls

Comment: `symlink("home/apuntes", "home/scripts")` is different from the shell command `ln -s /home/apuntes /home/scripts` because your symlink call doesn't have a leading forward slash. Is that your problem?

Comment: Also check `$!` for errors if you're not already doing that.

Comment: I'm cheking and It throws: The file already exits.

Comment: $! is only meaningful after an error; if symlink is returning 1 it isn't

Comment: Hi Ghafit, when I first read your question, I didn't realize you wanted to create a link *inside* `/home/scripts`, which is what your answer does. I edited your question to make this more clear, please edit again or rollback my edit if I misinterpreted you.

Answer (score 4):

Perl's `symlink` doesn't support passing a directory instead of a link name the way you can with `ln`. You have to pass the link name:

```
symlink('/home/apuntes', '/home/scripts/softlinkname');
```

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot this is a discrepancy between ln and perl's symlink; ln has a `ln TARGET DIRECTORY` form as well as the `ln TARGET LINK_NAME` form, but symlink only has the latter.  so this is a good answer, but the question was lacking the details of what was actually wanted (and where the OP said symlink was returning 1 they were presumably mistaken)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `symlink('/home/apuntes', '/home/scripts')`?   (Your question mentions it without the / before home.)  It should work, returning 1 on success and 0 (and setting $!) on failure.

But normally only root would have write access to `/home`; are you running it as root?

This works fine for me:

```
sudo perl -wE'say symlink("/home/ysth","/home/xysth") || "Error: $!"'
```

printing 1 the first time and "Error: File exists" the second time.

Running `sudo strace perl -wE'say symlink("/home/ysth","/home/xysth") || "Error: $!"'` gives (after a lot of other stuff):

```
symlink("/home/ysth", "/home/xysth")    = 0
write(1, "1\n", 21
)                      = 2
```

and running a second time gives:

```
symlink("/home/ysth", "/home/xysth")    = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
write(1, "Error: File exists\n", 19Error: File exists
)    = 19
```

What happens when you try?

Comment: Yes, I'm running it as root and I have also tryed symlink('/home/apuntes', '/home/scripts')

It returns 1, and does not create the softlink

Comment: What OS is this? Maybe try running it under strace and see if that tells you anything?

Comment: updated answer.  and are you certain you have the parameters in the correct order (existing file first, new symlink name second)?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem recently, but then it turned out that I had a leading whitespace in the argument I was passing in the method to my method which was calling the symlink with the same arguments. Check out for these small details. I'm sure it would work!

Answer (score -1):

What about

> system(" ln -s /home/apuntes /home/scripts");

Comment: The question is about Perl, not Python. Even if you drop the Python-specific import, though, there's no reason to use `system` when there's a built-in command that does the same thing.

Comment: I can not use system calls :s